# Android - How to get TimeZone Value from milliseconds

Tags: android

In Android how to get TimeZone value(GMT+8.00) from milliseconds long value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [TimeUtils.getTimeZone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimeUtils.html#getTimeZone%28int,%20boolean,%20long,%20java.lang.String%29) method: you give it the offset, daylight savings time, the time in milliseconds and a country and it gives you back a TimeZone.